GKE autoscaling doesn't scale due to quota issues (it says I used 250GB SSD when I used only 50GB), is there a way to force cleanup?
GKE autoscaling doesn't scale due to quota issues (it says I used 250GB SSD when I used only 50GB), is there a way to force cleanup?
gcloud compute disks list
NAME                                      LOCATION    LOCATION_SCOPE  SIZE_GB  TYPE         STATUS
pvc-8dfc9e8e-ee3a-479f-8b0d-244b23499fb1  us-west3-b  zone            50       pd-balanced  READY


